# Google custom search sort date range criteria not working

Tags: javascript, api, search, google-custom-search

In Google Custom search we pass date range criteria in sort parameter

```
http://www.example.com/search?cx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:yyyyyy_yyyyy&q=google&sort=date:r:20160304:20160505.
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search#restrict_to_range
```

But we are not getting expected result as per the date range criteria. 
After debugging the code the sort parameter is not getting passed to custom search URL even when we are passing it on to our search page url.

**Google Custom search URL:**

```
https://cse.google.com/cse?q=google&r=m&cx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:yyyyyy_yyyyy&fexp=20606&client=google-coop&hl=en&type=0&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&format=p4&ad=p4&nocache=1081472127237880&num=0&output=uds_ads_only&source=gcsc&v=3&allwcallad=1&adext=as1%2Csr1%2Cctc1&bsl=10&u_his=50&u_tz=330&dt=1472127237882&u_w=1366&u_h=768&biw=1349&bih=233&psw=1349&psh=233&frm=0&uio=uv3st16sd13sv13lhsl1sr1cc1-&jsv=14100&rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fsearch%3Fcx%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_yyyyy%26q%3Dgoogle%26sort%3Ddate%253Ar%253A20160304%253A20160505
```

But when we try to access the direct API with sort date range parameter we are getting expected results.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=google&cx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:yyyyyy_yyyyy&sort=date%3Ar%3A20160701%3A20160724&key=<APIKEY>
```

We are using Google custom search V2 implementation.

Thanks,
Anup

Comment: It will be helpful to share your *JavaScript codes (for the generation of the Google Custom search URL)* so the community could look closely for a possible fix.

Answer (score 2):

Try to escape all special characters which are passed as query parameters. For example

```
>  - &lt;
<  - &gt;
&  - &amp;
'  - &#039;
'' - &#034;
```

These are encoded like this. You can escape it in two ways

1. explicitly specifying `escapeXml = "**false**"`   as the default value will be true.
2. Add the url in JSP if you are using 
   `<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>` and then escape by calling 
   `${fn:escapeXml(myString)}`.

Comment: @Anup you can try this option too

Comment: @Anirudh - JFYI I have used JS implementation of GCE.

Comment: @AnupKhandelwal - I understand that you ahve used `<gcse:search>` its a normal search tag within namespace `gcse` . These are basically javascript namespaces. I do think you can use escapeXml with the tag you want to escape special character.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an issue with your url parameters encoding. It might be double encoded.

Answer (score 1):

I think in code ur doing any escape characters for the query params try to remove that check

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using correct format.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=searchterm&sort=document-weight
```

Thanks!